# Laravel Paginator's "append" generates different key for array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5.5 with PHP 7.0, trying to create and append some queries to pagination following the docs.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#displaying-pagination-results

However with some queries which have multiple values, rendered links have different keys.

Simplest reproducing code is:

```
>>> User::query()->paginate(30)->appends(['query' => ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']])->nextPageUrl()
=> "http://homestead.app?query%5B0%5D=foo&query%5B1%5D=bar&query%5B2%5D=baz&page=2"
# expecting "http://homestead.app?query%5B%5D=foo&query%5B%5D=bar&query%5B2%5D=baz&page=2"
```

In other words, the next url of `/user?page=1&query[]=1&query[]=2` should be:

`/user?page=2&query[]=1&query[]=2`

but actually

`/user?page=2&query[0]=1&query[1]=2`

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Please follow this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I followed the document as I said. The document just says "You may append to the query string of pagination links using the `appends` method" so I used `append` method but the rendered link has additional key.